# Can you use the AWS Appsync query writer to test IAM users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Is it possible to simulate a signed in user with IAM auth on the appsync web based query tool?  If you have cognito choosen as the auth type, there is a little web tool to sign in as a user, but if i choose IAM, theres doesn't appear to be a way to do this.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whichever IAM user you want to interact with the console, but you will have to sign in via the normal AWS Console sign-in pages.

When you create your IAM user, click the checkbox for enabling `AWS Management Console access`. This will enable a password to be created for the IAM user so you can sign in to the AWS Console.

This will allow you to sign in, as the given IAM user, and use the AppSync Console.

Here's some documentation on how to sign in as an individual IAM user: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_how-users-sign-in.html